# Safely change home directory

Tags: cygwin, etcpasswd

I'm trying to safely update the home directory as specified in `/etc/passwd`,
but the standard Linux utils - usermod and vipw - for doing so aren't provided
by Cygwin.

Could anyone tell me how they changed this in Cygwin?

Comment: The duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1494658/923560 provides answers for recent Cygwin versions beginning with 1.7.34.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change my Cygwin home folder after installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ended up exiting all my cygwin shells and editing it by hand in a text editor. So far, so good.

Note: don't escape the spaces in the "Documents and Settings" directory. The entry will look like

```
user:...:/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/user:/bin/bash
```

The line is tokenized on the `:` character.

Comment: This works for UNC paths too, thanks was overriding with HOME variable before

Comment: What do I have to edit by hand? I don't know why my cygwin home directory is /cygdrive/c/Users/JoseAngel/AppData/Roaming/SPB_16.6 I want it to be C:/Users/MyName/

Answer (score 95):

**EDIT:** For recent versions of Cygwin (1.7.34 and beyond), see [this newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494658/1858225).

Like sblundy's answer, you can always edit by-hand.

But if you want to do it the "official" way, use the cygwin-specific [**`mkpasswd`**](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html) command.  Below is a snippet from the official docs on [`mkpasswd`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html) :

> For example, this command:
>
> **Example 3.11. Using an alternate home root**
>
> ```
> $ mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd
> ```
>
> would put local users' home directories in the Windows 'Profiles' directory.

There's a bunch of other really useful commands described on the [**Cygwin Utilities**](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html) documentation page (which includes `mkpasswd`). The use of `cygpath` in the example above is another of these cygwin-specific tools.

While you're at it, you probably also want to read the [Using Cygwin Effectively with Windows](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) documentation.  There's a bunch of really good advice.

Comment: If you're on a domain, you may consider this alternate command: (`-d` for domain)

    `$ mkpasswd -l -d -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

This didn't work for me - it basically hung. Since I'm the only one using this machine, I could use this alternative, which should be safe whether or not you're on a domain (the `-c` is for "current user)

    `$ mkpasswd -l -c -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

Comment: After doing this, the .bashrc doesn't seem to get read, even if I copy it to my new `$HOME`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Output should be _appended_ (>>) to /etc/passwd (for corporate scenarios with several users).
This worked ! :)

Comment: use uname -r to see which cygwin version you're on

Answer (score 16):

The simplest answer I have found is to make /home to be a soft link to your Windows Home/UserProfile directory

```
cd /
mv home oldhome
ln -s "$(cygpath -H)" home
```

I used cygpath as it will get the proper location for the HOME directory on the current version of Windows.  On my box `cygpath -H` returns `/cygdrive/c/Users`

Comment: After doing this for some time there is one drawback:  I have to run it each time I update cygwin using their setup.exe.  Not a big deal but something to remember.

Comment: This is the best answer. I wonder why cygwin does not default to `cygwin -H` by default. It is the most sensible location, and since Windows 7 there is no space in its path too.

Comment: on another note, this will not work. It suddenly decided to ignore the symbolic link!

Comment: You have to reapply it when you run setup again.  That is the only time it has failed for me.  I have not tried it on windows 10 yet  though

Comment: Works as expected on Windows 10.  I still have to re-apply each time I update cygwin.

Answer (score 8):

For the current user the following worked for me:

1. Close Cygwin.
2. Set the HOME Windows user environment variable.
3. Start Cygwin.
4. run "mkpasswd -c -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd".
5. Restart Cygwin.

I confirmed it worked by running ssh-keygen without any arguments. After making this change the app now defaults to saving the key to /cygdrive/c/Users/user instead of /home/user.

I don't know if setting HOME is required, but I did it anyway per instructions for setting up TortoiseGit with Cygwin using Tortoise's official documentation for unofficial Cygwin support [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-main). Setting HOME alone though was not enough for ssh-keygen to recognize the home directory change.

Also, note that Cygwin's official documentation on this issue can be found [here](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#utils-althome-ex).

Confirmed in Windows 7 using 64-bit Cygwin v1.7.35.

Comment: For Cygwin 1.7.35+ use of mkpasswd is discouraged in favour of /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 4):

I always set HOME as a user-specific environment variable in Computer Properties.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that as it is set to a corporate network drive. Looks like it would work though.

Comment: Note that this will not work for ssh, it explicitly ignores the HOME and always uses /etc/passwd. See last sentence of http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.home.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid problems caused by having spaces in the path to your home directory, use the short-form of the Windows 'Profiles' directory - i.e. `/cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/user`.

You can do this by typing the command:

```sh
mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath $(cygpath -dH))" > /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 3):

> Original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182877/193617) by [Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193617/christopher) from [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494658/193617)

#### Cygwin 1.7.34+

For those using **Cygwin 1.7.34** or higher Cygwin supports configuring how to fetch home directory, login shell, and gecos information in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. This is detailed in the Cygwin User Guide section:

- [Cygwin user names, home dirs, login shells](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-passwdinfo)

If you've previously created an `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` file you'll want to remove those and configure Cygwin using the new Windows Security model to POSIX mappings.

```
[[ -f /etc/passwd ]] && mv /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak
[[ -f /etc/group ]] && mv /etc/group /etc/group.bak
```

The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file's `db_home:` setting defines how Cygwin fetches the user's home directory. The default setting for `db_home:` is

```
db_home: /home/%U
```

So by default, Cygwin just sets the home dir to `/home/$USERNAME`. You can change that though to point at any other custom path you want. The supported wildcard characters are:

- `%u` The Cygwin username (that's lowercase u).
- `%U` The Windows username (that's uppercase U).
- `%D` Windows domain in NetBIOS style.
- `%H` Windows home directory in POSIX style. Note that, for the `db_home:` setting, this only makes sense right after the preceeding slash, as in `db_home: /%H/cygwin`
- `%_` Since space and TAB characters are used to separate the schemata, a space in the filename has to be given as `%_` (that's an underscore).
- `%%` A per-cent character.

In place of a path, you can specify one of four named path schemata that are predefined.

1. `windows` The user's home directory is set to the same directory which is used as Windows home directory, typically something along the lines of `%USERPROFILE%` or `C:\Users\$USERNAME`. Of course, the Windows directory is converted to POSIX-style by Cygwin.
2. `cygwin` AD only: The user's home directory is set to the POSIX path given in the cygwinHome attribute from the cygwinUser auxiliary class. See also [the section called “The cygwin schema”](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch-cygwin).
3. `unix` AD only: The user's home directory is set to the POSIX path given in the unixHomeDirectory attribute from the posixAccount auxiliary class. See also [the section called “The unix schema”](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch-cygwin).
4. `desc` The user's home directory is set to the POSIX path given in the home="..." XML-alike setting in the user's description attribute in SAM or AD. See the section called “The desc schema” for a detailed description.

The following will make the user's home directory in Cygwin the same as is used for the Windows home directory.

```
db_home: windows
```

#### Cygwin 1.7.33 or earlier

For those using **Cygwin 1.7.33** or earlier, update to [the latest version Cygwin](https://cygwin.org/install.html) and remove previously used `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files, then see the steps above.

Else, follow these older steps below.

Firstly, set a Windows environment variable for HOME that points to your user profile:

1. Open *System* on the *Control Panel*
2. On the *Advanced* tab click *Environment Variables* (toward the bottom)
3. In the User Variables area click "New…"
4. For Variable name enter `HOME`
5. For Variable value enter `%USERPROFILE%`
6. Click OK in all the open dialog boxes to apply this new setting

Now we are going to update the Cygwin `/etc/passwd` file with the Windows `%HOME%` variable we just created. Shell logins and remote logins via `ssh` will rely on `/etc/passwd` to tell them the location of the user's `$HOME` path.

At the Cygwin bash command prompt type the following:

```
cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak
mkpasswd -l -p $(cygpath -H)  > /etc/passwd 
mkpasswd -d -p $(cygpath -H)  >> /etc/passwd
```

The `-d` switch tells mkpasswd to include DOMAIN users, while `-l` is to only output LOCAL machine users. This is important if you're using a PC at work where the user information is obtained from a Windows Domain Controller.

Now, you can also do the same for groups, though this is not necessary unless you will be using a computer that is part of a Windows Domain. Cygwin reads group information from the Windows account databases, but you can add an `/etc/group` file if your machine is often disconnected from its Domain Controller.

At the Cygwin bash prompt type the following:

```
cp /etc/group /etc/group.bak
mkgroup -l > /etc/group 
mkgroup -d >> /etc/group
```

Now, exit Cygwin and start it up again. You should find that your HOME path points to the same location as your Windows User Profile -- i.e. `/cygdrive/c/Users/username`

Comment: As the paths follow predefined schema with latest Cygwin instead of "moving" home directory I'd recommend to use symlinks (including Windows native) to particular directories from the `HOME` directory.

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep my cygwin installation sync'd to a pen drive and another computer, so I hate hard-coding the home directory. I use the following cygwin.bat:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL
set SHELL=\\bin\\bash
set HOME=%~dp0..\..\doc\unix
bin\bash --login -i
ENDLOCAL
```

SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL make sure that SHELL and HOME don't clobber existing env variables for other programs. `HOME=%~dp0..\..\doc\unix` sets HOME to be two directories up, in the doc/unix subdirectory. Then in ....\doc\unix.bashrc, I include `PATH="/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/bin"`.
I did not use `start /wait %CD%\bin\bash` to start bash, because I am using [Console2](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/console_portable), so I don't need an additional cmd window.

Answer (score 2):

## Using Windows Environment Variable: HOME

This works for me for a permanent, non-portable, non-network solution; i.e. setting the HOME Environment variable permanently in Windows.

**Note** that this doesn't affect *ssh* or *telnet* sessions which always refer to */etc/passwd*

*[ref: Setting up Cygwin- My HOME environment variable is not what I want.](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.home)*

### CMD

For *current* user (needs to run once per user)::

```
reg add HKCU\Environment /v HOME /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%USERPROFILE^%
```

For *new* Users:

```
reg add HKU\.DEFAULT\Environment /v HOME /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%USERPROFILE^%
```

**Note:** Carets ^ *before* percent-signs %

### IMPORT REG FILE

Import this reg file (*current* user):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"HOME"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,00,00
```

For *new* users:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKU\.DEFAULT\Environment]
"HOME"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,00,00
```

### REGEDIT

In Regedit, under:

For *current* user:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

For *new* Users:

```
HKU\.DEFAULT\Environment
```

Create **HOME** as a new *Expandable String Value* (*REG_EXPAND_SZ*) and put in **%USERPROFILE%**

Comment: Whatever information this answer was based on, it is no longer current. The _ref:_ link is also broken. I would not try this at home.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /home
rm -rf chris
ln -s /cygdrive/z chris
```

I am not really sure if it is the safest solution but it is a possible solution that works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I edited my /etc/passwd file directly (making sure nothing else would be accessing it), and changed all references to /home to be /Users (on Windows 7).  I found that, in order for everything to work correctly, I had to delete any directories in the /home directory (or move them to the appropriate other location).  Otherwise, cygwin would develop a split personality where, for example, 'bash -l' would start in /home/Pablo but $HOME would be /Users/Pablo and emacs would appear to do the reverse.  Once I deleted /home/Pablo, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to be in `C:\Users\username` when I start cygwin. So, I just added to `.bashrc` and `.profile`

```sh
cd ${HOMEPATH}
```

If you prefer to use `~/.` instead of `$HOMEPATH`, you can also add the following:

```sh
export HOME=${HOMEPATH}
```

This way I don't disturb the cygwin installation.