# Setting default path with Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, filepath

I've got a Cygwin installation, and I'd like it to start Bash in a certain directory whenever I start up. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc`, You can <strike>either change your `$HOME` to that directory, or you can</strike> [tried and it didn't work] add a `cd` to that directory at the end of the file.

Comment: Where and what the hell is a `~/.bashrc`? Edit: The whole file appears to be a gigantic comment.

Comment: `~` is a shortcut for your [home directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/what-exactly-is-a-home-directory), which is where you log in.  It's usually `/home/username` where `username` is your actual username.  `.bashrc` is a file that bash reads when you log in to set up the environment the way you want it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `~/.bash_profile` you may simply write `cd /cygdrive/c/path/to/where/you/want/cygwin/to/start`. You will find this file in your cygwin installation folder, under `<path_to_cygwin>\home\<user>\.bash_profile`. (In my case: `C:\cygwin64\home\User\.bash_profile`).

Comment: worked perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**python script**

!!before use add .bashrs any string to the end!!

use name_script.py c:\path

path_bachrc - path to .bashrc

cmd - path to cygwin.bat

```
#***********************************************#
#   gangelXXX@gmail.com                         #
#***********************************************#
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

path_bachrc = 'c:/PP/cygwin/home/adm/.bashrc'
cmd = 'c:\PP\cygwin\Cygwin.bat'

def delEndLineFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        aList = f.readlines()

    bList = aList[0:-1]

    with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
        fd.writelines(bList)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("newPath", type=str, help="New path in .bachrc cygwin")
args = parser.parse_args();

delEndLineFromFile(path_bachrc);

p = args.newPath;
pNew = 'cd /cygdrive/' + p[:1] + p[2:].replace('\\', '/')
print(pNew)

with open(path_bachrc, 'a') as f:
    f.write(pNew)

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash on Cygwin starts up in your home folder, just like on Linux, which Cygwin mimics as closely as it can. So, you simply need to [change your home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation/1494721#1494721).

(Note that your Cygwin folder need not be the same as your Windows user home folder. By default, they are different, but you could make them the same by putting something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/myid` into your Cygwin user entry in `/etc/passwd`.)