# Windows 8.1 why does RabbitMQ dont work?

Tags: php, erlang, rabbitmq

Hi i can't run RabbitMQ service or broker

`--old non important removed content--`

please help me, how can i fix it ? i have instaled newest erlang x64 version

@UPDATE

here after changing the `RABBITMQ_BASE` i still got this error
how it looks like now:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 27-Aug-2014::12:30:52 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.70.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {badarg,
                                 [{io_lib,format,
                                      ["~-15s: ~s~n",
                                       ["home dir",
                                        [67,58,92,85,115,101,114,115,92,82,97,
                                         102,97,322]]],
                                      [{file,"io_lib.erl"},{line,154}]},
                                  {rabbit_misc,format,2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,'-log_banner/0-lc$^1/1-1-',2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,'-log_banner/0-lc$^1/1-1-',2,[]},
                                  {rabbit,log_banner,0,[]},
                                  {rabbit,start,2,[]},
                                  {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,272}]}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 133)
    ancestors: [<0.69.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.71.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.69.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 222
  neighbours:
```

and from console

```
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,badarg}

Log files (may contain more information):
   d:/Program Files (x86)/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-3.3.5/base/log/rabbit@
VARDIUS.log
   d:/Program Files (x86)/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-3.3.5/base/log/rabbit@
VARDIUS-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{could_not_start,rabb
it,badarg}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

d:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.5\sbin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ is trying to print out the following message:

```
              RabbitMQ 3.3.5. Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: C:/Users/Rafał/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@VARDIUS.log
  ######  ##        C:/Users/Rafał/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@VARDIUS-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...ok
```

But it fails to do so, because on one hand the filename is given as a Unicode "string", i.e. a list of code points (note the 322 in the middle, which stands for `ł`), but on the other hand RabbitMQ is trying to print this as a non-Unicode string (using the `~s` directive instead of `~ts`).

I'd suggest you report this as a bug to the RabbitMQ developers.  Meanwhile, you could try running it from a directory whose path doesn't contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: so do yu know how to change rabbits log path ?

Comment: if i set `RABBITMQ_BASE` system environment variable to another location following this https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html
will i have to restart rabbitmq ?

Comment: updated my answer, it doesnt help just message is displayed correctly

Comment: Still the same problem, but with a different message: now it's trying to print your home directory.  Not sure how to make Erlang use a different directory as home directory...

Comment: i will leave the topic open for some days maybe someone know solution for this, if for some time noones naswer i will accept your answer. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. My workaround solution was to insert an additional batch line in `rabbitmq-server.bat` or `rabbitmq-service.bat` files:

```
SET HOMEPATH=\SOME_PATH_WITHOUT_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS
```

`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` is used  as a path where the `.erlang.cookie` file is stored. I've also set `RABBITMQ_BASE` to some non-ascii path too, like you did.

This solution was inspired by [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25892818/543205).