# Trouble with changing Cygwin home folder

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cygwin

I'm trying to change my Cygwin home folder. To do this I followed Christopher's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation), but I'm having some trouble with the instructions given there.

After doing all of this my home directory was changed to `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/%USERPROFILE%`

There are several things I don't seem to understand:

1. I expected the home directory to be changed to `C:\Users\Myname`.
2. `%USERPROFILE` is not a directory that I can see anywhere, so I have no idea what it is.
3. Having changed the home directory, Cygwin doesn't read the .bashrc file automatically anymore since it's in `/home/myname` or whatever and I don't see where I should add the .bashrc file for it to be seen.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! In fact it's better to do what you did and post a new question with a link to another question or answer, explaining your particular circumstance, so thanks for doing that! I've gone ahead and fixed up a bit of the formatting -- hope I haven't changed anything that's too important. I'd like to recommend taking a look at what we're [about], just as a guide to what's acceptable here, what's not and to learn a few of the customs around here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's `%USERPROFILE%`, not `%USERPROFILES%`; make sure you have the correct name. It is a variable reference, so you have to expand it. In the environment variables settings it should be expanded, so if it isn't, you most probably have a typo there.

Please, check in `cmd.exe`. A command `echo %HOME%` should print

```
C:\Users\Myname
```

(that is the expected home directory). If it does not, the variable is not set correctly and the rest of the instructions won't work.

However there is another way, which I consider easier. Mounting `C:\Users` on `/home` in `/etc/fstab`. I have entry like:

```
c:/Users /home ntfs binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0
```

Whether you want `posix=0` and `noacl` is up to you. They disable the attempts of cygwin to simulate unix permissions using ACLs. Since you want your user profile and cygwin home dir to coincide, I suppose you mix cygwin and native applications and the access control lists generated by cygwin often complicate that.

Comment: echo %HOME% prints "%USERPROFILE%"

Comment: @user22277: Than the setting is incorrect for some reason. What does `echo %USERPROFILE%` print?

Comment: When setting the HOME variable do I put "%USERPROFILE%" as its value or "C:\Users\Myname" ?

Comment: @user22277: You can put `%USERPROFILE%`, but it must not be quoted (`"%USERPROFILE%"`).

Comment: I put quotes to signify text in between. Anyway I still don't understand why it's not working. Should I change it from "%USERPROFFILE%" to "C:\Users\Myname"?

Comment: Moral of the story: I changed HOME value to C:\Users\Myname. Now it works. I still don't understand why %USERPROFILE% didn't work. So about the second part of my question, should I put a .bashrc file in C:\Users\Myname?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for future reference:

I had the same issue, and I believe it is because `%USERPROFILE%` is defined as a **User variable** rather than as a **System variable**.

I therefore defined `HOME = %USERPROFILE%` as a User variable and it worked.

Right now I am not 100% sure if there are any other impact in putting `HOME` in User variables, but so far so good. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem on a brand new Cygwin installation.  I was getting the following error when launching Cygwin.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/"C:': Permission denied
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/"C:/Users/[username]" could not be created.
Setting HOME to /tmp.
```

I determined this error was coming from the `/etc/profile` script where the `HOME` directory is set.  After reading the comment from @Jan-Hudac on the Windows `HOME` environment variable definition where `%USERPROFILE%` should not have quotes around it, I checked the `HOME` User Environment Variable in Windows and found that it was defined as `"%USERPROFILE%"`.  I removed the quotes and the Cygwin shell started correctly in the correct home directory.  Thanks for the insights!