# How to make babun/cygwin home directory equal windows home directory?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cygwin, home-directory

I just installed babun, a variant of Cygwin. I want the cygwin user home directory to equal my windows home directory.
So, to be clear, I don't want to add the cygwin home to the `C:\Users` as a new user, I want it to be the same as my current windows home directory.

Now, according to this post, [How can I change my Cygwin home folder after installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation), there is a neat way to make the cygwin home directory point to your windows home directory.
You open the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and make sure is has a line `db_home: windows`. However, after restarting my pc,  `echo $HOME` still says `/home/chiel.tenbrinke`, which is not what is should be. It should say something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/Chiel.tenBrinke`.

Why is this not working?

My cygwin version is `CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW IM-Chiel-2015 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) 2015-03-04 12:07 i686 Cygwin`.

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain why you think this question is not a good fit?

Answer (score 4):

Babun has a surprisingly good FAQ. The last entry in the FAQ is [How to Use the Windows home directory as Babun's home directory](http://babun.github.io/faq.html#_how_to_use_the_windows_user_profile_directory_as_my_home_directory_in_babun)?

For me, it boiled down to:

1. Create an env var for $HOME = /Users/my_account_name via Win+R `sysdm.cpl`
2. Run `mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`
3. Run `babun install`

I'm not sure why Babun doesn't recognize the standard cygwin setting in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and I'm a bit surprised there was no mention of this setting in the Cygwin FAQ. I'm a bit concerned that in spite of what a great collection Babun is, it may fall out of sync with Cygwin quickly if not properly maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an easier way and works perfectly so far.

Just mv your home folder to the location you want, and make a symlink

The first execution after move may prompt errors, run babun install will fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/nsswitch.conf

db_home: /cygdrive/c/Users/%H

Comment: This answer would benefit from additional detail/explanation.  See [answer].