# Why I can`t go to the desktop in terminal (babun)

Tags: bash, babun

I cant go to my desktop using `cd` command.
There is

> no such file or directory

error.
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: I suppose babun uses a different home directory than windows. Print the current working directory with the `pwd` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute path like `cd /user/home/*YOUR_USERNAME*/Desktop` please be advised that Unix bash is case sensitive.

If this don't work you can still run the `ls - all` command in your home directory to see all folders and files inside.
If you see the "Desktop" folder and just can't change into the directory try using `sudo cd ~/Desktop`

Hope that helps.

Comment: cd /user/home/*YOUR_USERNAME*/Desktop - doesnt work.
And when I use "ls - all" - I can`t see the Desktop

Comment: Then you simply don't have any "Desktop" directory in your home folder.
You can create it using `mkdir Desktop`

Comment: Wait) How can I possibly have no Desktop directory in my home folder?)
It is located in C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop.
In Command Prompt I just print " cd Desktop" and it works. But in this Unix console I cant do this...





`{ ~ }  » cd /user/home/Oleg/Desktop                                                             ~
cd: no such file or directory: /user/home/Oleg/Desktop
`

Comment: That is indeed odd. Please provide the output of `ls -all` after `cd /` and after `cd ~` for further information.

Comment: 1. https://ibb.co/kwtdi6
2. https://ibb.co/gz9OGR

And here is the view of the home folder:
https://ibb.co/bu9vVm

Comment: Ok now it makes kinda sense. Seems like your babun home directory doesn&amp;amp;#39;t match your windows home directory.
Actually it is a known problem that babun uses an own directory structure when installed with default configuration.
A solution for this issue is already provided by @ouwen [here] [1]

[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011250/how-to-make-babun-cygwin-home-directory-equal-windows-home-directory