# Cygwin initial directory in unknown location

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, cygwin

I'm usually a Linux command prompt user, now I'm using Windows 10 on my laptop instead, I know... poor choice. So I'm using Cygwin as my terminal on windows, the only problem is when I started it for the first time, it initializes in a directory I don't recognize

[image: ![Cygwin upon start]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVLJd.jpg)

I would like to be able to navigate to my Documents and Desktop folders to access where my code files are stored. Below is another screencap of what I see after using 'ls' and 'cd ..' commands.

[image]

I've spent far too much time navigating all these directories visible, and I can't seem to find where my files are located in the system. So how do I find them? How can I set Cygwin to always start in the proper directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate to a directory in C:\ with cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850920/how-to-navigate-to-a-directory-in-c-with-cygwin)

Comment: See also [how to access different directories outside cygwin home dir](http://superuser.com/q/229870/16275)

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin creates a POSIX-like file system layout inside the install directory (normally `C:\cygwin`), and thats what's mounted as `/` inside Cygwin.

The "real" Windows file system is mounted as `/cygdrive`, so `/cygdrive/c/cygwin` is a recursive directory that has the same contents as `/` (if that helps visualize the relationship).

Your Windows user home directory (not to be confused with the Cygwin directory inside `C:\cygwin\home\USERNAME`) is located in `/cygdrive/c/Users/USERNAME`. If you wanted you could add the following to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Users/$USER"
```

To start your shell in your Windows user directory. Personally, I find in practice I rarely actually need to end up in Windows-land while working in Cygwin, but to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to change the `C:\cygwin\etc\nsswitch.conf` file in the following way:

The %H variable represents the Windows home directory in POSIX style, so add it to the `db_home:` line and uncomment the line.

Example:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch    
# Defaults:
# passwd:   files db
# group:    files db
# db_enum:  cache builtin
db_home: /%H/home
# db_shell: /bin/bash
# db_gecos: <empty>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839331/7243543) for more information on how to change Cygwin's defaults by editing the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

More info: the root directory `/` is `c:\cygwin` (or `c:\cygwin64` on a 64-bit installation) by default, so everything exists under there. <strike>Changing the setting above will make a symlink in `c:\cygwin\home` corresponding to your profile directory in Windows, usually `c:\Users\<username>` referenced by the environmental variable `%userprofile%`.</strike>

**Edit:** *The last sentence isn't correct. What actually happens is that your home directory will change to `/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>`*

One last useful tip: if you want to verify which directory you're in, relative to Windows' directory structure, you can run the following at the cygwin prompt:
`explorer.exe .`

(Note the `.`) This opens up an explorer window in your current directory.

I think the simplest answer to your question is that you can navigate to any directory on any drive (i.e. `C:`, `D:`, etc) by replacing the drive letter with `/cygdrive/<letter>` (i.e. `C:\` can be accessed at `/cygdrive/c`)