# .bashrc in Cygwin 1.7

Tags: cygwin

I'm running Cygwin 1.7.17 on Windows Server 2012. My user account is "Administrator". Where should I put a .bashrc file for the Cygwin bash to pick it up?

I've tried the "c:\users\Administrator" folder, which seems to be the HOME in Cygwin 1.7. Tryed c:\cygwin\home\Administrator also.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Start a shell instance and run the command `echo $HOME` to see what your home path is set to. That's where all your user config files will be read from. It might not be one of the paths you tried.

Once you know where it is, just copy the template `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files from the `/etc/skel` folder to get you started.

If you don't like the path that's currently being used as your home, you can change it by editing `/etc/passwd`. Here's more info on that... [Safely change home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225764/safely-change-home-directory-in-cygwin)

Comment: `echo $HOME` shows `/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator` , but putting .bashrc in c:\Users\Administrator does not work - I've put `echo TEST` in the file, but nothing is printed on login

Comment: Have you copied the .bash_profile template to your home too? It contains all the logic to source .bashrc when. Make sure to add it if you don't already have it. `cp /etc/skel/.bash_profile $HOME`

Comment: `cygpath -w ~` will show you the windows path `c:\cygwin64\home\administrator`

Comment: `bash: cd: /etc/skel: No such file or directory` -> Turns out, you have to run `cygpath -w /etc/skel` as administrator. For some reason, it still does not exist and I cannot `cd` into it.